# Get value from XML file from web

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

Get sunrise time and sun set times from xml from web.
This is the link to the xml:

http://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Oslo/Oslo/Blindern/varsel.xml

I have tried to use the information in the:
http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/25/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-25-talking-to-external-apis/

I am trying to change his information to my information by doing this but is only getting NullReferenceException:

```
private void GoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        WebClient twitter = new WebClient();

        twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
        twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Oslo/Oslo/Blindern/varsel.xml"));
    }
}

void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null) return;

    XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

    string name = xmlTweets.Element("weatherdata").Element("location").Element("country").Value;
    TwitterName.Text = name;

}
```

Here is a clip from the xml file from the net. It is quite big, but i only need  the time for sun set and the time for sun rise.. Please help.

```
<weatherdata>
<location>
<name>Blindern</name>
<type>Byområde</type>
<country>Norge</country>
<timezone id="Europe/Oslo" utcoffsetMinutes="120"/>
<location altitude="90" latitude="59.9406284402542" longitude="10.7230684724138" geobase="ssr" geobaseid="73738"/>
</location>
<credit>...</credit>
<links>...</links>
<meta>...</meta>
<sun rise="2012-05-19T04:30:13" set="2012-05-19T21:58:34"/>
<forecast>...</forecast>
<observations>...</observations>
</weatherdata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is already at the `<weatherdata>` node, so you don't need to query for it again.

```
string name = xmlTweets.Element("location").Element("country").Value; 
TwitterName.Text = name;
```

Comment: Oh my God, Thanks:) How can i get the <sun rise="2012-05-19" value?

Comment: Use the `Attribute` method instead of the `Element` to get to the `rise` attribute: `xmlTweets.Element("sun").Attribute("rise").Value`